# how can I get a value of an object from inside an object

Tags: javascript

I need to access values of an object, object A for example, from inside object B, where object B is inside object A. More specifically, object B has a function that is going to change the value of object A, but the function can't change the value of object A because object B is in the way.

I want `doThing` to change the value of `part()`. The problem is because `doThing` is inside `exampleObj` so when `doThing` uses `this.x++` the function tries to change the `x` of `exampleObj` , even though it doesnt have an `x` value.

```
var doThing = function() {
    this.x++;
}

var exampleObj = {
    action:doThing
}

function part(x,y,obj) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.exampleObj = obj;
    
    this.function = function() {
        this.exampleObj.action();
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no automatic link from a child object to its parent.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you might be able to achieve it via arrow functions. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: @PrerakSola That won't work, `doThing` won't inherit that scope of `this`.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah you are right. Tried implementing that but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no link from `exampleObj` back to the `part` object.

You can bind the function to `this` when calling it.

```js
var doThing = function() {
  this.x++;
}

var exampleObj = {
  action: doThing
}

function part(x, y, obj) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.exampleObj = obj;

  this.function = function() {
    this.exampleObj.action.call(this);
  }
}

p = new part(1, 2, exampleObj);
p.function();
console.log(p.x, p.y);
```